# Is there an IDE that can do intelligent navigation through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, ide, navigation, aptana

In Java world I always press **F3** if I want to jump into a method or class, variable... anything really.

I am now working on a Javascript project and I am finding the F3 (Open Decleration) extremely limiting in Eclipse and in Aptana. Its actually almost non-existent, working only for declared variables in methods.

Our project has grown to about 50 Javascript files (~60 Javascript "objects"), and things are becoming almost unmanagable because of situations like this :

```
this.url = Util.buildURLFor(URLs.ticketPrefillData);
```

The **Util** object is in a *file* called **Toolbox**, and the **URLs** object is in a *file* called **URLManager**. The question is, how is anyone supposed to know that it is in the Toolbox file? And why can't the IDE pick out all the objects in all the files, so the F3 knows where to go.

As the javascript files grow it is becoming unmanageable (in an agile project this can be fatal) and we are thinking of switching back to Java in the form of Vaadin or ZK, unless we can find a decent intelligent IDE for code navigation.

In Summary, I need a JS IDE which can do this :

I have a method in file A which calls a method on class B1 which is in file B. It seems like no IDE i have come across can make that association.

Comment: They don't make that association because there is no way to tell for sure: JS is a scripting language, therefore there are no "strict" relationships between files. You may have 10 methods in 10 different files which fit your method calls, and which one is executed is up to which files you've loaded at the moment. The fact that there is no "include" concept makes things even harder.

Comment: yes, but cant an IDE make an educated guess at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by JetBrains. I haven't used it but have heard great things about it. It supports [code navigation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#Code_Navigation_and_Usages_Search), and judging by ReSharper, JetBrains are really good at it.

Currently, I use Visual Studio 2012, which has great (enough, for me) navigation when you add references to your used javascript files. So in file A, when you use code in file B, you would just add this to the top of your file:

```
/// <reference path="./B.js" />
```

From now, you have Intellisense and code navigation. (VS2010 has similar features but isn't as powerful, if I recall correctly)

(your question is however kind of subjective, so might get closed/flagged; try to avoid asking questions where you ask people what they use/prefer; see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for more info)

Comment: what makes it subjective? Is it the use of the word "best" ?

Comment: Yeah sort of. But essentially you're asking a list of links to tools, which is a hard question to answer. Everyone has his/her preference, so there isn't really one specific answer. I've asked questions like this that were flagged. As you are new to SO, I don't want to do this, but others are more strict in these matters.

Comment: thanks for the advice. But can webstorm deal with the F3 situation as described by me?

Comment: I like Notepad. It's the "bestest". :)

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more info.

Comment: alright i will try out webstorm, and see if it solves my "I have a method in file A which calls a method on class B1 which is in file B."

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that WebStorm does do exactly what i was requiring with Code Navigation.

Comment: @Oliver, you don't need to comment if you find a post is the correct answer. You can mark it as such with the green checkmark under the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: can you change " It should " to "it does" ?